# Ambiguity when linking statically and dynamically

Tags: c++, linux, linker

I have an executable E that links to libA.1.a, it also links to libB.so.

libB.so links to libA.4.so.

but since libA.1.a is loaded along with executable I suspect libB.so also uses libA.1.a and i think this might lead to unexpected crashes. I do not have control over what version of libA.x.so libB.so links to, but i need to use libA.1.a myself.

Is there any way its possible to get this working, to make the statically linked version of libA.1.a unavailable to libB.so?

libA is a C library libB and E are c++

```
          E
       /     \
      /       \
  libB.so     libA.1.a
    |
 libA.4.so
```

Edit: 
libA.1 and libA.4 are from different versions of same library.
The api (hence exports?) of libA.1 and libA.4 would be almost be similar but the implementation would definitely have changed between them.

Comment: Why do you link libA is two different forms?

Comment: I don't link one of them (libA.4.so), some one else gives it to me. and I have source code only for libA.1.a.

Comment: I can't see how this setup makes sense. You need to expand your question to explain the relationship between what's in `libA.1.a` and what's in `libA.4.so`. Same or different exports? Same or different implementations? If different why are they both called `libA`?

Comment: have added the response in question